# w3wp.exe why it is only one in task manager?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis, webserver

**Worker Process:**  Worker Process (w3wp.exe) runs the ASP.Net application in IIS...

**Application Pool:** Application pool is the container of worker process...

Took it from [here](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/03/14/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-how-iis-process-asp-net-request/).

Having all this i can assume to see more than one w3wp.exe process in Task Manager if i have more than one application hosted on IIS, and have problems for example to attach to process from VS(which w3wp.exe to choose). But there is no such problem.

How that works?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but make sure you have "Show processes from all users" and "Show processes in all sessions" checked off in the "Attach to Process" screen. I've been unable to see w3wp.exe in that list without those checked in the past.

Comment: There are other facts you miss, such as "an application pool can host multiple applications" and "there are other mechanisms to shut down idle worker processes". What you observe is normal and you just need to learn more about IIS.

Comment: So does that mean that if i will run two different applications in two different app pools i'll see two w3wp.exe in task manager?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy yes, 1 application pool = 1 w3wp